# Proof mistake: Induced operator on $C_\lambda^* (G)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, completely-positive-maps

In the paper "An Example of a Non-Nuclear $C^*$-algebra, which has the Metric Approximation Property", Haagerup proves the following lemma:

**Lemma 1** Let $\varphi$ be a positive definite function on a discrete group $\Gamma$. There exists a unique, completely positive operator $M_\varphi: C_\lambda^* (\Gamma) \xrightarrow{} C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ such that for all $x \in \Gamma$,
$$
M_\varphi \lambda_x = \varphi(x)\lambda_x.
$$

I understood his proof, but I am questioning why isn't this immediate in the sense that for all $x \in \Gamma$ and $f \in \ell^2(\Gamma)$,

$$
\| \varphi(x)\lambda_x f \|_2 \leq \|\varphi\|_\infty \| f \|_2 = \varphi(1) \| f \|_2
$$
$$
\implies \| \varphi(x)\lambda_x \| \leq \varphi(1)\|\lambda_x\|.
$$
Why doesn't this fact imply immediately that the operator defined on $\{\lambda_x :x \in \Gamma\}$ extends to a bounded operator on $C_\lambda^* (\Gamma)$ such that
$$
\|M_\varphi \| \leq \varphi(1)?
$$

Asking this because Haagerup's proof, although relatively easy, is quite more elaborate than this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Proving $||\varphi(x)\lambda_x|| \leq \varphi(1)||\lambda_x||$ is not enough to establish the norm of $||M_\varphi||$. To do that, you need to consider linear combinations of $\lambda_x$ instead of just $\lambda_x$ by itself. (Consider, for example, that on the set $\{\varphi_x\}$ the reduced $C^\ast$ norm and the universal $C^\ast$ norm coincide. That of course does not mean the two norms are the same.)

Comment: Your reasoning does not make use of the positive definiteness of φ,
 except that the maximal value is attained at the identity element of the group. So it cannot be correct.

Comment: By the way the estimate $\|M_\varphi\|\le \|\varphi\|_\infty$ cannot hold for all bounded functions $\varphi$ for $\Gamma =\mathbb{Z}.$ Haagerup's paper contains a beautiful result that the function $r^{|x|},$ $0<r<1$ is positive definite on the free group, where $|x|$ denotes the length of the word $x$ in it's reduced form. But it is possible to indicate a explicit unitary representation of the free group for which $r^{|x|}$ is a diagonal matrix coefficient, so positive definiteness follows.

Comment: @DavidGao Ah that's it! Thank you so much.